# LIBGDX finding which object collided with its fixtures

Tags: libgdx

I'm doing a simple jumper game and have problem with collisions. In project I have Player and Platform Class. The player is overriding shouldCollide(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB) method. My questions is, if there a way to get with fixtureA and fixtureB is the player collide with platform? I read demos at github of libgdx, but project there(Superjumper) it seems isin't using a box2D so i'm little consufed about how i should proper make collision in my project.

My current shouldCollide looks now like this:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldCollide(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB) {
    if(fixtureA == fixture || fixtureB == fixture){
        return body.getLinearVelocity().y< 0; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comparing both fixtures(A and B) with fixture can show me if player is one of "collision makers"(sorry for that but i cannot find proper word in english) only becouse its defined in Player class same like method.

I found that i can add string to userData in Fixture in my Platform Class, then in shoudCollide I must only get that userData, i wonder if its good way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found that i can add string to userData in Fixture in my Platform Class, then in shoudCollide I must only get that userData, i wonder if its good way to do this.

Actually you can put any `Object` in your user data.

In case you really have only platform and player, you might do something like the following. Please note that this is just a quick demonstration and it doesn't cover all cases (like player vs player collision, or platform vs platform collision). For more complicated scenarios, you'd probably have to find a more generic algorithm which works using reflection.

```
Player player = ...;
playerFixture.setUserData(player);

Platform platform = ...;
platformFixture.setUserData(platform);

...

@Override
public boolean shouldCollide(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB) {
    if (fixtureA.getUserData() != null && fixtureB.getUserData() != null) {
        Player player;
        Platform platform;
        if (fixtureA.getUserData() instanceof Player) {
            player = fixtureA.getUserData();
            platform = fixtureB.getUserData();
        } else {
            player = fixtureB.getUserData();
            platform = fixtureA.getUserData();
        }

        // now you have full access to the player and the platform
    }

    return false;
}
```

For a collision *filter* this might be a bit too overpowered, but as soon as you have to implement collision *handlers*, you will need to have the real entities, instead of just `Strings`.